# material-ui-phone-number unmounted component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

New to REACT so bear with me please:

I am getting the following error after adding the [material-ui-phone-number](https://github.com/alexplumb/material-ui-phone-number) plugin:

```
Uncaught Invariant Violation: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.
    at invariant (http://localhost:8080/public/bundle.js:96969:15)
```

My component's render function looks like the following:

```
  class CreateUserDialog extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        defaultValues: {
          username: '',
          name: '',
          phone: ''
        }
      };

      this.handlePhoneChange = this.handlePhoneChange.bind(this);
   }
   handlePhoneChange(value) {
     if (value) {
      this.setState({ phone: value});
     }
   }
   render() {
    return (
     <Dialog open={this.props.open} onClose={this.props.onClose}>
      <DialogTitle title="New User" />
      <DialogContent>
      <Formik
        initialValues={this.state.defaultValues}
        onSubmit={values => {
          this.props.onSubmit(values);
        }}
        validateOnBlur
        validate={values => {
          const errors = {};
          return errors;
        }}
        render={() => (
          <Form>
            <Grid container direction="column" className={this.props.classes.dialogContainer}>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid item xs>
                  <TextField name="name" label="Name" required data-cy="user-firstname" />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <MuiPhoneNumber name="phone" label="Phone Number" data-cy="user-phone" defaultCountry={"us"} onChange={this.handlePhoneChange} />
              <TextField name="username" label="Username" required data-cy="user-username" />
              <Grid container justify="flex-end" className={this.props.classes.buttonContainer}>
                <Button
                  color="primary"
                  className={this.props.classes.cancelButton}
                  data-cy="cancel-create-user"
                  onClick={this.props.onClose}
                >
                  Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" data-cy="create-user">
                  Create New User
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Form>
        )}
      />
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>
 );
}
}
CreateUserDialog.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
export default withStyles(styles)(CreateUserDialog);
```

How do I get this to work inside this code base (beyond the example given in the README)?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it but you are missing a closing brace `}` for your `CreateUserDialog ` class

Comment: Ah, that was a copy pasta error when typing out the question.  The brackets are balanced in the code base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce your error, but here is a CodeSandbox that seems to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/0x7mqonlw0

The only change I made, other than add a bunch of imports, was to add a `value` prop on the phone number:

```
        <MuiPhoneNumber
            name="phone"
            label="Phone Number"
            data-cy="user-phone"
            defaultCountry={"us"}
            value={this.state.phone}
            onChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
          />
```

I think, however, that it is somewhat luck that it worked for me. There are some notable issues with the `material-ui-phone-number` package. It has React and Material-UI as dependencies rather than peerDependencies and the versions that it has are not up-to-date, so you are very likely to end up with two versions of React and Material-UI being pulled in if you also have them specified in your own package.json. Having two versions of React can cause a multitude of possible problems.

The `material-ui-phone-number` package is not popular in the slightest which means there could be plenty of other issues waiting for you if you continue trying to use this package.